# Query to get reposts from people the user is following

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have a table `posts` where all the posts by users are stored, the structure of this table is as follows

```
| post_id | post_user | post_content | post_date |
```

the users table is as follows

```
| user_id | username | user_joined |
```

user relationship table is as follows

```
| follower | following | rel_date |
```

this is the query I am using to get the posts from people that user is following to show them.

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_user in(SELECT follower from user_follow where following=$loggedin_user)`

Now I want users to share posts, for which I created a table repost_user as follows

```
| repost_user | original_post_user | post_id | repost_date |
```

I want to get posts from people that user following, which includes reposts too.. How do I do this?

**EDIT** : How my resultset should look

`post_id | post_content | post_user | post_date | is_repost | repost_user | repost_date`

for eg if its normal post the row should look like

`23 | <some content> | 3 | <post date> | false | null | null |`

if its a repost the rows would be

`23 | <some content> | 3 | <post date> | true | 2 | <repost_date> |`

Answer (score 0):

Is that what You want ?

```
SELECT post_id,
post_content,
post_user,
post_date, 
if(repost_user.post_id is null, 0,1) is_repost, 
repost_user,
repost_date 
FROM posts
LEFT join repost_user 
on posts.post_id=repost_user.post_id
WHERE (repost_user in
           (SELECT  follower from user_follow where following=$loggedin_user)
 or post_user in
           (SELECT  follower from user_follow where following=$loggedin_user) )
AND posts.post_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks @jaczes , pls look at the question, I have edited it with what and how I want to be the resultset...